# How to port NetBeans ant build into build server (Atlassian Bamboo)

Tags: java, ant, bamboo

I'd like to have my NetBeans project build in bamboo. Most of it seems to be working but I'm not able to launch my project like I can when I build in NetBeans.

When I build in netbeans it (by the default ant build) sticks my dependent libraries into a directory called dist/lib/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar and my jar is created in: dist/MyJar.jar. I can run my jar by typing

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

and it will find my dependent libraries. However when I build in bamboo there is one thing different that I noticed which is my libraries did not get copied to dist/lib/. but since they are in the root of my project its not a problem i just go ahead and recopy them from my /libs/ to /dist/lib/ and then i try the "java -jar MyJar.jar" command but i get this error:

```
james@build.mycompany.com:~dist/$ java -jar MyJar.jar 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/StandardDeviation
    at readnthvalue.App.<clinit>(App.java:26)
    at readnthvalue.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:31)
    at readnthvalue.MainFrame.lambda$main$0(MainFrame.java:365)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.StandardDeviation
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

Any thoughts or advise from someone with knowledge in ant and atlassian bamboo is greatly appreciated.

I should mention that the md5sum is different from the working jar and the one built with bamboo.

I use the command: ant clean jar to build from command line

**UPDATE 8-04-2017**

I noticed that on bamboo I get this:

```
build   04-Aug-2017 14:02:51    -do-jar-jar:
build   04-Aug-2017 14:02:51    [j2seproject1:jar] Building jar: /home/filtec/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUR-ATP-JOB1/dist/auratec-helper.jar
build   04-Aug-2017 14:02:51         [echo] To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
build   04-Aug-2017 14:02:51         [echo] /home/filtec/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/bin/java -cp /home/filtec/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUR-ATP-JOB1/libs/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:/home/filtec/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUR-ATP-JOB1/libs/jcommon-1.0.23.jar:/home/filtec/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUR-ATP-JOB1/libs/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar:/home/filtec/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUR-ATP-JOB1/libs/jSerialComm-1.3.11.jar:/home/filtec/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AUR-ATP-JOB1/dist/auratec-helper.jar filtec.auratec.MainFrame
```

but in NetBeans I get this output:

```
Building jar: /home/james/NetBeansProjects/auratec-helper/dist/auratec-helper.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "/home/james/NetBeansProjects/auratec-helper/dist/auratec-helper.jar"
```

So I guess my new updated question is why is the build on the bamboo server different in behavior from on my workstation. What are the dependent jars not copied and why am i able to use the -jar option to run the files where as on the build server i need to use vanilla java to run when building from an ant script on the bamboo server.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't put in dist folder anything. It's only for build and will clean every time. Colud you pack you netbeans project to archive and share it via any available service. ex: http://dropcanvas.com

Comment: I probably am following the best practice for the dist dir and am using the NetBeans default behavior wiping the dist dir clean and copying release jars into the dist folder. BTW its NetBeans that originally does that with its default build script.

Comment: here is a link to my project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5FRf3pjR6UBQmVRY1B4QlB4a2M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pain to figure out. Basically the copylibstask.jar needed to be available to ant on bamboo but because NetBeans is not installed on the build server we need to reference it manually. I've placed a copy into /libs/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar and am referencing it in the project.properties file.

```
# this is needed for the ant build
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=libs/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

The libraries are now copying and the jar is executable again.